# How to assign a sub parameter in a POST HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, rest, httpurlconnection

I'm attempting to do an HttpURLConnection POST request to a webservice API.

The body of the request requires 2+ levels of parameters, for instance:

```
<fields>
  <field>title</field>
  <field>description</field>
</fields>
```

Right now I have this, which gives me a 500 error:

```
 URL url = new URL(strUrl);

 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
 conn.setRequestProperty("field", "title");
 conn.setRequestProperty("field", "author");
 conn.connect();
```

I've connected to this via Firefox's RESTClient but can't do it through code.

How do I assing each `field` value with `.setRequestProperty`?  I'm also open to better ways of doing this request.

Comment: you need to create the XML document and POST it to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing won't work, HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty is used to set HTTP headers.

You need to create the XML document and POST it to the server.